# Looking for step-by-step instructions on how to install Bakery module

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, single-sign-on, instructions

I am looking for step-by-step instructions on how to install Bakery module for Drupal.
I have multiple sites, that do not share a Drupal installation & tried understanding instructions mentioned at http://drupal.org/node/962932, however they are too complicated.
Newbie to Drupal, make things difficult.

Comment: Are you certain that you want to use Bakery? If you're a "newbie", you might want to see if something easier to configure, such as OpenID, would meet your needs. I've been using the OpenID Selector module a lot lately: http://drupal.org/project/openid_selector It streamlines the login process with OpenID, so that it works a lot like Stack Overflow's login process.

Answer (score 0):

I uploaded the instructions for how I did something like this at http://drupal.org/node/962932

What specifically more do you need to understand?  Perhaps I can help.

Comment: Thanks Dominic for stopping by. I have two separate Drupal installations http://jobs.learners.ws & http://news.learners.ws. These are two separate installs. I have almost decided to go with open ID or facebook connect.